# Achartengine bar labels...call items within a series?

Tags: android, bar-chart, achartengine, label, series

I am using Achartengine to generate a stacked bar graph.  It works fine and displays the values for the bottom portion of the bars.  The thing is, sometimes I need to turn off some of the labels but now all of the labels.  It looks like the software can either turn all labels on or all labels off.

```
setChartSettings(renderer, "Gym Attendance", "", "", 0.5, 12.5, 0,
            24000, Color.BLACK, Color.BLACK);
    renderer.getSeriesRendererAt(0).setDisplayChartValues(false);
    renderer.getSeriesRendererAt(1).setDisplayChartValues(true);
    renderer.setShowLegend(false);
    renderer.setMargins(new int[] { 80, 10, 60, 10 });
    renderer.addXTextLabel(1, "Rec. Hall" + "\n" + "(240 max.)");
    renderer.addXTextLabel(2, "White" + "\n" + "Building" + "\n"
            + "(210 max.)");
    renderer.addXTextLabel(3, "IM" + "\n" + "Building" + "\n" + "(60 max.)");
    renderer.addXTextLabel(4, "Fitness Loft" + "\n" + "(40 max.)");
    renderer.setXLabelsColor(Color.rgb(0, 0, 0));
    renderer.setYLabelsColor(0, Color.BLACK);
    renderer.setYLabels(10);
    renderer.setXLabels(0);
    renderer.setXAxisMin(0);
    renderer.setXAxisMax(5);
    renderer.setYAxisMin(0);
    renderer.setYAxisMax(250);
    renderer.setAxesColor(Color.BLACK);
    renderer.setXLabelsAlign(Align.CENTER);
    renderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.LEFT);
    renderer.setPanEnabled(false, false);
    // renderer.setZoomEnabled(false);
    renderer.setZoomRate(1.1f);
    renderer.setBarSpacing(0.5f);
    renderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
    renderer.getSeriesRendererAt(1).setGradientEnabled(true);
    renderer.getSeriesRendererAt(1).setGradientStart(0,
            Color.rgb(180, 180, 180));
    renderer.getSeriesRendererAt(1).setGradientStop(65,
            Color.rgb(25, 25, 112));
    renderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(220, 220, 220));
    renderer.setMarginsColor(Color.rgb(248, 248, 255));
    renderer.setOrientation(Orientation.HORIZONTAL);
    renderer.setZoomEnabled(false, false);

    return ChartFactory.getBarChartView(context,
            buildBarDataset(titles, values), renderer, Type.STACKED);

}
```

This is the problem line

```
renderer.getSeriesRendererAt(1).setDisplayChartValues(true);
```

I need to be able to turn the labels off for each member of the series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot turn on only some of the chart values. As long as they don't overlap, they will all be displayed.

However, please note that support for annotations has been recently added. You can do something like:

```
series.addAnnotation("text", x, y);
```

This way you can add only the annotations you want.

Comment: It's not working...do I have to set a boolean to 'true' first?  I tried renderer.addAnnotation(text,x,y)

Comment: renderer.addAnnotation() doesn't exist. I wrote series.addAnnotation(), where series is an XYSeries.